Movie with word play in the beginning?
I have seen this clip a very long time ago and I think it was actually from the beginning of a comedy.
There is a man (called Jack) sitting in a car and a few guys walk by saying "hi". Then another guy comes with a shotgun, saying "Hijack!" (word play) and the main character just hits the gun, and the hijacker shoots his foot.
The scene is very clear in my mind (at least I think it is), so hopefully I have described it good enough.

I just searched this key word " Hi jack hijack" in Youtube and there were videos over there.

It may be from the South African movie Panic Mechanic.  
You can see the "Hi Jack" scene on YouTube.

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

There is a scene similar to this at the beginning of some broadcast versions of Airplane (1980), although it happens in an airport, not in a car, and there's no gun play (that I recall).


Some broadcast versions have an additional scene at the airport in which a couple recognizes someone they know. "Hi, Jack!" they yell to him, causing airport security personnel to grab him and haul him away. (source)


